# Is my understanding of the relative adverb "where" correct?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns, relative-adverbs

**My question:**

I am afraid I explained the relative adverb "where" wrong, especially in the (3). Is my understanding about the relative adverb correct?

---

**Let me tell you what I might have been wrong about**

Earlier today I was teaching my friend how to read the following sentence:

> This system is loaded with a smart mechanism, **where** the server responds to the user's questions without human help and sends alert notifications to the user when there is an anomaly.

She didn't understand why the **"where"** can be used like that. She thought it should have been **"which."**

Then I explained:

> (1) This system is loaded with a smart mechanism, **where** the server responds to the user's questions without human help and sends alert notifications to the user when there is an anomaly.

is equal to

> (2) This system is loaded with a smart mechanism, **in which** the server responds to the user's questions without human help and sends alert notifications to the user when there is an anomaly.

is equal to

> (3) This system is loaded with a smart mechanism, **which** the server responds to the user's questions without human help and sends alert notifications to the user **in** when there is an anomaly.

Comment: I think the  word "whereby" would have been a better choice there. AHD:  " In accordance with which; `by or through which`."

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you. I feel a little uncertain about my example (3). In accordance with "by which" or "through which" you provided, I think example (3) can become: This system is loaded with a smart mechanism, "which" the server responds to the user's questions without human help (a)"by/through" and sends alert notifications to the user (b)"by/through" when there is an anomaly. Are both of the (a) and (b) necessary?

Comment: @vincentlin Just remember that "where" is an adjunct of place in the relative clause, typically having a prepositional paraphrase such as in/to/from some place. I'd say that "in which" is wrong in [2] unless it can mean "from which". Better might be "a smart mechanism, which responds to the user's questions without human help and sends alert notifications to the user when there is an anomaly". Does that convey the right meaning?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, it works. You revised the sentence and made it clear. However, this sentence is something I came up with to explain the use of "where" to my friend. When I broke it down and analyzed it from "where" to "in/to/from which" to "which...in/to/from", I feel I might not be certain about the last form. Clearly my example sentences are not good for a discussion about that because it has some grammar errors as you guys mentioned.

Comment: Are you trying to explain something that you found in a users' manual?  It *is* hard to explain how this "where" works.  The reason for that is that *it doesn't work*.  If it did work as written, then this should also work:  "This system is loaded with a smart mechanism, where the server sends alert notifications to the user."  The original sentence is just as ungrammatical as this abbreviation, assuming that the smart mechanism doesn't actually *receive and hold* those user notifications.  "Which" doesn't work, "where" doesn't work, and I'd edit the original to say "such that".

Comment: My friend saw a sentence similar to this: This is a beach, where people play volleyball and take a sunbath. She didn't know why the "where" is there and thought it should be replaced by "which". I said it can be that way because "which...in/at/from" can be "in/at/from which..." and then it can be just "where", because "this is a restaurant, which I eat food at" is correct and makes no different if "which..at" replaced by "where". But the original sentence is long and followed by an adverb clause (when...), so I am kind of unsure if I am right or wrong, so I asked this question on this site.

Comment: It's much easier to describe how "where" works in that sentence, since it does work well there.  The answer to "where" is something like "here".  The answer to "which" is something like "this one".  We can understand "This is a beach.  People play volleyball **here**".  If we can't understand "People play volleyball **this one**", then we can't understand "This is a beach **which** people play volleyball".  We'd need something like "This is a beach **on which** people play volleyball" or "This is a beach **which** people play volleyball **on**", to match "People play **on this one**".

Comment: Your analogy between "which" and "this one" is helpful and something I haven't thought about. Thanks. So I can confidently say that the original sentence confusing her can be like this: This is a beach, "which" its members party at night and take a sunbath "at" when the sun comes out. It is grammatically correct but just not a very elegant way to write. Am I right? I also asked that question in another post (https://reurl.cc/xZrz5L), and many people said it is not grammatically correct, but I wonder whether they are just talking about style rather than grammar.